# Still use excel whilst running VBA

Tags: vba, scroll, wait

I wrote some code in vba.

When I run it, Excel stops responding temporarily - the pointer changes to the busy symbol and I can't scroll down.

I would like to continue using Excel whilst this code is running.
How can I achieve this?

Here's the code:

```
numRowB = getRow("B")
numRowL = getRow("L")
For i = 6 To numRowB
    count = count + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & count & "/" & numRowB - 6 & " items."
    For j = 6 To numRowL
        If RE6(Range("B" & i).Value) = RE6(Range("L" & j).Value) Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = count
            Range("K" & j).Value = count
            If Range("B" & i).Value <> Range("L" & j).Value Then
                ReDim Preserve arrData(count2)
                arrData(count2) = Range("L" & j).Value
                count2 = count2 + 1
                Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                Range("K" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
            Else
                Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                Range("K" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

Place `DoEvents` within your second for loop. This will allow Excel to respond to mouse and keyboard input whenever the code hits the `DoEvents` command, which should be rather often.

**Warning:** If you actually use `DoEvents`, you should also make sure to specify which worksheet you are using your Range calls on (which you should generally do anyway). You could do this by doing something along these lines:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
With sheet
     'Your code goes here...
end With
```

Then make sure you use `.Range` instead of `Range`, so that even if the user changes sheets it will still update the correct sheet.

Comment: +1 for a correct answer as well as caution when using `DoEvents`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. It's in your best interest that Excel macro will finish as soon as possible. In order to improve its performance and reduce blinking, use `Application.ScreenUpdating=false` in the beginning, and `Application.ScreenUpdating=true` in the end of your macro.

A nitpick: You can use Cells(row,column) if you're querying a single cell. This accepts integers as arguments, so `Range("K" & i)` will be changed into `Cells(i,11)`. This is a bit faster.

Comment: Also, the most obvious would be to use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` after. This speeds up macros by a very large factor when the workbook is of decent size.

Comment: Well, this depends if his sheet has a lot of formulae. If yes, definitely this will rock, although I'd save current value in that case. I usually deal with those sheets that only have data in them, so this was out of my scope. Thanks for mentioning, though.

Comment: I work with sheets with hundreds of formulas with huge ranges (10-40k cells in the range) so that came naturally ! :D

Comment: `You cannot` <-- what? See the other answer.